# Find the measure of $DME$

Tags: geometry, quadrilateral

In the parallelogram $ABCD$ $A$ is the small angle and $BC=2AB$. We draw the height $CE$ to $AB$.We draw a line from $C$ and $E$ to $M$. if $M$ is the midpoint of $AD$ find the measure of $DME$ in terms of $AEM$.

I really cannot do anything special but I have drawn a picture May helps.

[image]

Comment: Triangle $CDM$ is isosceles; maybe that can buy you something.

Comment: Yes I know I found It but them I stop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Show that each of the two triangles $\triangle CME$
and $\triangle CDM$ is isoceles.
This gives you several angle equalities,
which (added together correctly) will give $\angle DME$
as a multiple of $\angle AEM$.

A first step that might help is to let $N$ be the midpoint of segment $CE$.
Then $MN$ is parallel to both $AE$ and $CD$,
and you will find that $\triangle CNM$ and $\triangle ENM$
are two congruent right triangles.

Comment: Note that CME isn't isoceles please edit or delete it.

Comment: CME is Isosceles.  Prove it!

Comment: Yes right up vote.

Comment: It may help to draw the diagram to scale.  $AD$ is less than twice the length of $CD$ in your diagram.  That's why the triangles that should be isosceles don't look isosceles.

Comment: The funny thing is, before posting this answer I posted a comment on the question, but it turned out I had missed one of the isoceles triangles myself, causing me to come to the wrong conclusion! (The comment is deleted now, because it was incorrect.)

Comment: @DavidK I commented above on your answer, but was directing the comment to Taha.  Sorry for the confusion.  I probably should have commented on the question instead.

Comment: @John No problem; my comment about my earlier error was mainly in response to the sequence of comments before yours, although the lack of correct scale in the diagram _may_ have contributed to the error as well.